# how to send json data headers to api

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to send SMS through my web app, I bought bulk SMS from SMS supplier, trying to engage with their api.thanks in advance for your help

I post the data through postman and it works (post method, headers section), when I post data from my webpage to their URL it doesn't work,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // Add event listener for opening and closing details
 $('#testbut').on('click', function() {
  var Username = 'xxxxxx';
  var password = 'xxxxx';
  var language = '1';
  var sender = 'RitaFoods';
  var Mobile = '2011xxxxx';
  var message = 'hello from the other side';
  $.ajax({
   url: "https://smsmisr.com/api/webapi/?",
   method: "POST",
   "headers",
   data: {
    Username: Username,
    password: password,
    language: language,
    sender: sender,
    Mobile: Mobile,
    message: message
   },
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(data) {
    alert("done");
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));;
   }
  })
 });
});
```

when I sending this data to another page on my web site, I received it with no problem , and i response with the parameters and alert it, when I sending to api url it gives no response, maybe because I need to send in headers section but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: `"headers": { }` try passing the headers inside the header property

Comment: "it doesn't work" — This is not a clear problem statement. What happens? What does the Network tab of the browser's developer tools show? What does the Console show? You have a `success` handler but no `error` hander, add one.

Comment: "I post the data through postman" — How is postman configured? What content-type are you encoding the data ask?

Comment: "maybe because I need to send in headers section" — What makes you think this?

Comment: sorry because it is not clear i am new in developing so i will check the network tab , and send screenshot, but i don't  know how to make error hander

Comment: You're making an HTTP request to a service which requires a username and password and then sends SMS to people (which usually costs money and is something spammers love). Handing that username and password over to everyone who visits your website seems like a terrible idea, so the API probably isn't designed to allow it, and once you look at the error messages I bet this will turn out to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068)

Answer (score 0):

You can set header with the `beforeSend` function

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://smsmisr.com/api/webapi/?",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    Username: Username,
    password: password,
    language: language,
    sender: sender,
    Mobile: Mobile,
    message: message
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('My-Custom-Header', 'My-Value');},
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (data) {
    alert("done");
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));;
  }
});
```

or via the  `headers` field

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://smsmisr.com/api/webapi/?",
  method: "POST", "headers",
  data: {
    Username: Username,
    password: password,
    language: language,
    sender: sender,
    Mobile: Mobile,
    message: message
  },
  headers: {
    'My-Custom-Header': 'My-Value',
  },
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (data) {
    alert("done");
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));;
  }
});
```

Comment: do you think i  must remove data field and add all the parameters in the headers field ?

Comment: that depends on the API requirements, look at their docs and see what goes in the payload and what in the headers

Comment: when i use postman i send all parameters in headers and it works , i will try it now

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the API documentation](https://smsmisr.com/API).

It says "Post in header not in body", but as a description of what you need to do, this is wrong.

Look at the examples. They show that the data is encoded in the **query string of the URL**. In HTTP terms, that means it goes in the start line, not a header.

---

So you need to do something like:

```
  var url = new URL("https://smsmisr.com/api/webapi/?");
  url.searchParams.append("Username", Username);
  url.searchParams.append("Password", password);
  // etc etc

  $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: "POST",
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(data) {
    alert("done");
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));;
   }
  })
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/19068) if you need compatibility with older browsers.

---

Be warned that you are likely to run into the problem described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068).

Answer (score -2):

try to add in your ajax

> contentType: "application/json"

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: **your URL**,
        data: **your DATA**,
        contentType: "application/json",
});
```

Comment: They are not posting JSON data. So that would be wrong.

Comment: @Quentin oh, sorry